# Suspend-to-ram fails on Gentoo with i915

Tags: gentoo, suspend, acpi, intel, i915

I am struggling with suspend-to-ram on my Acer Aspire V3 772G with Gentoo. My configuration:

- Gentoo 3.12.5 kernel ([.config](http://pastebin.com/0bWS0uFz))
- [/etc/portage/make.conf](http://pastebin.com/7dRrsYAD)
- [Portage world file](http://pastebin.com/80wQnTW7)

1) It works in Windows 7 and Linux LiveCD (Ubuntu 13.10). Therefore hardware is fine and it's not a general Linux issue, the cause must be in my Gentoo installation

2) On Gentoo it fails both in console and X (black screen after resume). In order to debug I tried the following:

```
dmesg > dmesg_before.ker; echo mem > /sys/power/state; dmesg > dmesg_after.ker
```

The results: [dmesg_before.ker](http://pastebin.com/W2HmU6jy) / [dmesg_after.ker](http://pastebin.com/6zYmTT36)

Since dmesg_after.ker was created, I can suspect BIOS resume works fine, but the graphics driver (i915) is the issue.

3) I wondered if it would work without i915 driver. Since it was built into kernel, I recompiled the kernel with the driver built as a module ([new .config](http://pastebin.com/fqkLxinS)) and:

```
dmesg > dmesg_before.mod; echo mem > /sys/power/state; dmesg > dmesg_after.mod
```

Suprisingly, the suspend failed stopping at "Suspending console(s)" message. It was both with i915 module loaded and unloaded. Here's [dmesg_before.mod](http://pastebin.com/rwSc4RPA).

4) I also tried other kernel versions (3.10.17, 3.12.0) and newest unstable xf86-video-intel package, but no luck, same results.

I feel this is something trivial, like some kernel parameter or a package missing, but I don't know how to debug it further. Any hints?

*EDIT*: I was actually able to type `touch TEST; reboot` blindly after resume. It means that the resume is in fact successful, the only issue is that the screen remains off.

Comment: Have you tried to run: `pm-suspend`  as superuser from a console?

Comment: I tried, but the result is quite the same as from `echo mem > /sys/power/state`.

Comment: Can you please file bugs for this?